# The argument type 'void Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool'

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

The Error is in the Title, I don't know what i've done wrong. The Problem occurs only for `() => deleteItem(key),` in the second last row. Thank you very much! This is my first project and I was thinking maybe there is an alternative for `` because this seems to be the problem. The code I posted here is just of the *ToDO* Class, and this is the only error that my Program (VSC) can find.

```dart
class ToDo extends StatefulWidget {
      const ToDo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _ToDoState createState() => _ToDoState();
    }
    
    class _ToDoState extends State<ToDo> {
      Map<String, bool> products = {
        'Tomate': false,
        'Käse': false,
        'Lauch': false,
        'Paprika': false,
        'Wein': false
      };
    
      void addItem(String item) {
        setState(() {
          products[item] = false;
        });
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      }
    
      void deleteItem(String key) {
        setState(() {
          products.remove(key);
        });
      }
    
      void toggleDone(String key) {
        setState(() {
          products.update(key, (bool done) => !done);
        });
      }
    
      void newEntry() {
        showDialog<AlertDialog>(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                content: TextField(
                  onSubmitted: addItem,
                ),
              );
            });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar:
              AppBar(title: Text('ToDo Liste'), backgroundColor: Colors.lime[500]),
          body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: products.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              String key = products.keys.elementAt(i);
              return SingleToDo(
                key,
                products[key]!,
                () => deleteItem(key),
                () => toggleDone(key),
///............
```

Comment: I don't know dart but maybe you forgot to call the function?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `SingleToDo` takes a bool as a second argument, you should replace `() => deleteItem(key)` by a boolean.

But you more likely to want to change the signature of `SingleToDo` second argument to `void Function()`.

Not related but important nonetheless: Dart supports named arguments, you should use often prefer use those are they are way clearer than nameless ones.